# Find all functions with given property

Tags: complex-analysis

Find all functions $f$ that are holomorphic on $B = \{z: -\pi/2 < \operatorname{Im}(z) < \pi/2 \}$ with $f(B) \subset B$ and such that $f(0) = 0$ and $f'(0) = i$.

Thoughts so far: My first thought was to try to apply the Schwarz Lemma somehow. So I found a sequence of conformal maps from the given region to the open unit disk, and indeed $0$ gets sent to $0$. But even if I find that the composition of maps is just a rotation, how do I figure out what this implies about $f$? Any hint would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\phi: B \to \Bbb D$ is a biholomorphic map from $B$ to the unit disk, then $$g := \phi \circ f \circ \phi^{-1}$$ is a biholomorphic map from the unit disk to itself. But we know (via the Schwarz Lemma) how to parameterize all such maps, and given any such map $g$, we can recover the corresponding map $f$ by conjugating $g$ with $\phi^{-1}$.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Do you think we use the fact that $f'(0) = i$ to show that the composite is a rotation?

Comment: Nevermind, I just got it. You can use this fact to show the derivative of the composite is $i$, which is good.

Comment: So when we conjugate $g$ with $\phi^{-1}$, do we end up with $f$ in terms of $\phi$? Do you think this is sufficient?

Comment: It depends on the framing of the question I suppose, but since you have $\phi$ written out explicitly, it shouldn't be too hard to compute its inverse, and hence to write out (the generic) $g$ as an explicit function of $z$.